# linux delete user account without userdel

Tags: linux

I'd like to delete a user from a tarball that contains the files for a Linux OS (it's a tarball of the root [/] filesystem).  Is there a way to do this completely and properly such that it would mimic the steps taken by the userdel command?  I suppose I have two choices:

1. Work within the OS on an actual target, use userdel and then re-tar
   the files.  Not a problem, but I was curious about acting directly
   on the tarball, hence...
2. I could mimic the steps taken by userdel: un-tar and delete all entries related to the user...according to the man
   page of userdel I would delete entries in /etc/group,
   /etc/login.defs, /etc/passwd, and /etc/shadow.  Then, re-tar.

Approach (2) is attractive because I could programmatically add or delete users directly on the tarball.  I'll try (2), but wondering if there would be any unintended consequences or leftover bookkeeping that I should do?  Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: For good measure you should record the uid and use **find /var /tmp -uid n** before you go and strike them from /place/where/untarred/etc/passwd ...

Comment: Good idea to track down any temp files...exactly the type of side-effect I was looking to cover.

Answer (score 2):

/etc/login.defs is only called when a new user is created. That file does not need to be modified. However, a mail spool will be created for the user in the location listed in login.defs

Deleting the user from /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd will work. /etc/group is not a requirement however it cant hurt. Those three files will take care of it, You may delete the mail spool if desired.

Comment: Great addition about the mail spool!